# Why this angular obj showing undefined though it has property

Tags: angularjs

```
function SettingCtrl( $scope, $location, User ){

  $scope.selectedMembership = User.membershipquery();

  console.log($scope.selectedMembership);

  console.log($scope.selectedMembership.id); //why returned undefined

}
```

It will give me in console,

> g {}ad_post_limit: "-1"ads_active_limit: "-1"ads_validity:
>   nullcategories_limit: "-1"category_floor_help_alert:
>   "6"category_floor_sale_alert: "5"contact_notification: "10"cost:
>   "0.00"extra_ads_listing_price: "25.00"extra_featured_ads_price:
>   "5.00"featured_ads_limit: "10"featured_ads_validity:
>   "30"floor_help_alert: "6"floor_sale_alert: "3"id: "1"max_ads_image:
>   "2"membership_title: "Free Membership"quote_notification: "10"slug:
>   "free-membership"validity: "-1"**proto**: Object []
>
> undefined

How to get that particular value in my controller function and manipulate with that.

Comment: Try `$scope.selectedMembership = JSON.parse(User.membershipquery());`

Comment: Can u give the output for 
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.selectedMembership));

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in $scope.selectedMembership . From your console log , it looks like its not in json format because of which $scope.selectedMembership.id always giving undefined as its not getting a proper object to read the value of id.

Comment: But when I used {{selectedMembership.id}} in view, it gives me actual value. If it is not in JSON format then how it could be?

Comment: if you are able to use as {{selectedMembership.id}} then are you not able to access it in your controller? though it does not look like a json format to me. JSON looks like this : {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}

Comment: No, I am unable to call the property in controller function. Is there any fundamental problem with angularjs as if it is not a JSON it won't give the value at the view but when I log out in the console it does not look like a JSON as you said earlier. Any more details you want to help on this, I'll sure provide you

Comment: Can you tell me what does this give you typeof yourVariable === 'object'   ?

Comment: it was an object. But I did a bypass but again I m in the same problem. Here  is my code

function DashboardCtrl($scope, User) {

  $scope.profile = User.userquery();
  $scope.classifieds = User.listclassifieds(status);
  $scope.membership = User.membershipquery();
  var mem = $scope.membership;
  console.log(typeof $scope.membership); //Object
  console.log(mem); //
  if( $scope.membership.validity == '-1' ){
    $scope.membershipValidity = 'Unlimited';
  } else {
    $scope.membershipValidity = $scope.membership.validity;
  }
}